# How can I automate the Tasklist command on my workstation to check a specific process on X number of servers?

Tags: batch-file, automation, cmd, tasklist

I'm trying to check what the status is on my XenApp servers for the spoolsv.exe process. I've got the command down to run individually from my XP workstation, but can't seem to get it to iterate through a text file. Here's what I have so far, what will make this populate Servers X-XX on my CMD screen?

```
@echo off

FOR /F "usebackq" %%G IN ("C:\Documents and Settings\userid\Desktop\Scripts\servers.txt") DO echo tasklist /S %%G /u domain\userid | find "spoolsv.exe"

pause
```

I can't seem to get it to run correctly, and sometimes it will just pop up my servers.txt file in notepad and not even run. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have it presented, tasklist never runs. The "do echo tasklist..." snippet means the literal string "tasklist /S server-one..." is being echo'ed to stdout. Since none of these literal strings contain "spoolsv.exe", the "find" command won't match anything.

Try the following instead:

```
@echo off

FOR /F "usebackq" %%G IN ("C:\Documents and Settings\userid\Desktop\Scripts\servers.txt") DO call :RunTasklistForOneServer %%G

pause
goto :EOF

:RunTasklistForOneServer

set ServerName=%1
echo Calling server %ServerName%
tasklist /S %ServerName% /u domain\userid | find "spoolsv.exe"
```

Comment: When i removed Echo, it just pulls up the results one by one really quickly then refreshes the screen and overwrites it with the next one on the list. I tested this by adding > output.txt to the end of the command. I'd like to have them be all listed going down the CMD window instead of overwriting each of the previous one everytime it iterates through the command.

Comment: Using > means that all standard output will go to output.txt. You won't see any standard output in your console if you use it. Remove the ">" if you want to see everything in your console. If you want to write the output to a file, use ">>" (two greater than characters) instead of ">". A ">" overwrites an existing file while ">>" appends.

Comment: Beautiful that code worked. Now if i could only get it to sit there longer before it went to the next one, i added a few more pauses but it still sometimes just goes to fast. Thanks bud!